# printf format parameter contain undefined escape character

Tags: c, string, escaping, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Hello\c!\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Output : `Helloc!`

So , when `\[some_undifined_symbol]`  appeared in `printf` 's format string, it just ignore the `\` ?

Comment: That's a lexical error, its treatment is compiler-dependent.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś means it is an undefined behavior ?

Comment: gcc says _warning: unknown escape sequence: '\c'_

Comment: This has nothing to do with `printf()`, it uses `%` for its formatting specifiers.

Comment: @unwind  Agreed.  This same problem would be seen with `const char *s = "Hello\c!\n"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\c` is not an escape sequence that is already defined, but it's better to avoid using it because it's reserved:

> #### C99 §6.11.4 Character escape sequences
>
> Lowercase letters as escape sequences are reserved for future standardization. Other
> characters may be used in extensions.

Comment: I cannot find an exact citation from the standard, but I suspect it's undefined behavior to use reserved escape sequences (as it happens when you redefine reserved identifiers).

Comment: Here is The Quote: `Escape sequences in which the character following the backslash is not listed in Table 7 are conditionally-supported, with implementation-defined semantics.` (`§2.14.3/3`)

Comment: @MarcinŁoś I looked up C++11 for your quoted part, so in C++ it's implementation defined. But I still can't one in C standard.

Comment: @Yu Hau - true, the question is about C, sorry.

Comment: It _appears_ that `\c` is simple not a "c-char-sequence" (6.4.4.4), there for not valid in "Hello\c!\n".  `\c` is not listed as an escape sequence, although it _looks_ like one.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following escape sequences defined for `c`:

- `\'`  single quote
- `\"`  double quote
- `\\`  backslash
- `\0`  null character
- `\a`  audible bell
- `\b`  backspace
- `\f`  form feed - new page
- `\n`  line feed - new line
- `\r`  carriage return
- `\t`  horizontal tab
- `\v`  vertical tab
- `\nnn`    arbitrary octal value
- `\xnn`    arbitrary hexadecimal value

Comment: The following are also C escape sequences `\?`, `\uXXXX`, `\UXXXXXXXX`.  X is a hexadecimal value.