# \c escape sequence listed in man but unkown in C

Tags: c, escaping, printf, gcc-warning

***I'm currently studying C, if this question seems an easy one or a newbie ones, then you know why.***

Reading the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf) for *printf* I found ***\c*** listed as an **escape sequence.** Its description is

> produce no further output

I've never seen and heard about ***\c*** prior to this moment. So I decided to try it out in a simple hello world program :

```
printf("\nHello World\n\n\c");
```

As a result, gcc gives me this warning :

> warning: unknown escape sequence: '\c' [enabled by default]

This sounds kind of odd for me, so I went trough it further investigating : I went to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) and ***\c*** wasn't listed as an escape sequence... Hence I tried searching around the web, and here on stack overflow. I've found very few references to ***\c*** (actually two) as discussed in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718787/printf-format-parameter-contain-undefined-escape-character) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154800/what-is-the-bash-escape-character-c) (I think that the latter isn't really related to C  but it seems that we are talking about "the same ***\c***", reading the description given).
Could somebody help  me to understand this thing?

Comment: I don't know of any working reference as in `C11` standard. can you link to the man page please?

Comment: @SouravGhosh http://linux.die.net/man/1/printf, it's also listed when I type man printf in a terminal.

Comment: isn't manpage 1 is for commands? Just saying, I did not see anything on man 3

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yes, I found it on manpage 1. If this can help I have tested it both on Ubuntu and on Elementary OS (lastest version)

Comment: MSVC gives *"warning C4129: 'c' : unrecognized character escape sequence"*

Comment: Man page for printf C function is `man 3 printf`. What you've seen is man for `printf` unix command.

Comment: I tried using `\c` in dash and bash and both of them print literally "\c".  zsh however does stop printing like the documentation says.  I guess there's a bash built-in printf because `/usr/bin/printf` works (which I guess is what zsh is using?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are *not* reading the correct man page. What you are looking at is: `man 1 printf`, which is about the shell command `printf`, not the C standard function printf.

Use:

```
 man 3 printf
```

to read about the C library function. `\c` is not in C and hence, it's not recognized by `printf(3)`.

The `printf(1)` you are looking at does work as documented.

```
$ /usr/bin/printf "ABC\chi"
```

produces:

```
ABC
```

Note that the Linux man pages in general may also have additional non-standard extensions (specific to Linux or glibc) and POSIX extensions etc. Non-standard extensions are usually documented as such but easy to miss. So if you are looking for what C standard says then you should look at the C standard. Here's an [online draft](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.2).

If you are wondering what the *number* passed to `man` is, it's the *section* number. `3` corresponds to library function. You can find details with: `man man`.
Here's summary of the sections:

> ```
>    1   Executable programs or shell commands
>    2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
>    3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
>    4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
>    5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
>    6   Games
>    7   Miscellaneous (including macro packages and conventions), e.g. man(7), groff(7)
>    8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
>    9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
> ```

Comment: Great summary! Where did you get it?

Comment: I thought it, but there isn't on OS X. Maybe I should consider to switch back to linux ...

Comment: That's the kind of answer I love to see here on SO. Really, thank you for your time.